# MSGEQ7 producing max output for all frequency bands

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, integrated-circuit, arduino-uno

I have been following a MSGEQ7 tutorial by J Skoba (http://nuewire.com/info-archive/msgeq7-by-j-skoba/) and have set up my circuit in the exact way he has:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And I'm using his code:

```
int analogPin = 0; // read from multiplexer using analog input 0
int strobePin = 2; // strobe is attached to digital pin 2
int resetPin = 4; // reset is attached to digital pin 4
int spectrumValue[7]; // to hold a2d values

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(analogPin, INPUT);
 pinMode(strobePin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(resetPin, OUTPUT);
 analogReference(DEFAULT);

 digitalWrite(resetPin, LOW);
 digitalWrite(strobePin, HIGH);

 Serial.println("MSGEQ7 test by J Skoba");
}

void loop()
{
 digitalWrite(resetPin, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(resetPin, LOW);

 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
 digitalWrite(strobePin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(30); // to allow the output to settle
 spectrumValue[i] = analogRead(analogPin);

 // comment out/remove the serial stuff to go faster
 // - its just here for show
 if (spectrumValue[i] < 10)
 {
 Serial.print(" ");
 Serial.print(spectrumValue[i]);
 }
 else if (spectrumValue[i] < 100 )
 {
 Serial.print(" ");
 Serial.print(spectrumValue[i]);
 }
 else
 {
 Serial.print(" ");
 Serial.print(spectrumValue[i]);
 }

 digitalWrite(strobePin, HIGH);
 }
 Serial.println();
}
```

And yet the output of the serial monitor is the max for all frequencies regardless of the input:
[image]

I have two of these chips and I have tried both and they both give the same result. I believe that both of these chips are faulty, or have I made some error?

Comment: With the info provided, we cannot possibly know if you have an error or if both chips are faulty. There is no way we can know how you connected them and if it is correct or not. If you do have a wiring error, the error could have damaged the chips, so they can be damaged now.

Comment: @Justme Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. I've added some pictures of my connections if that helps.

Comment: What value capacitors you used? Is the 200k resistor to pin 8 or 7, the pictures are quite blurry. Is the Arduino using 3.3V IO voltages, is the analyser chip also using 3.3V supply? It may not work with 3.3V IO if powered by 5V.

Comment: @Justme I used capacitors with 33pF, 100nF and 10nF as per the datasheet. The 200k is to pin 8. The arduino is powered by my laptop and the chip is powered by the 5v output of the arduino. The datasheet said the chip needed 5v.

Comment: But what is the supply of the AVR? Does the MCU run at 3.3V, because why else there would be 3.3V? And no the datasheet did not say the analyser chip needs 5V.

Comment: @Justme It's an Arduino Uno using the ATmega328 which has an operating voltage between 1.8 - 5.5v. The datasheet for the MSGEQ7 chip says that the min operating voltage is 2.7v the max is 5.5v and the typical is 5v. Have I misunderstood the question? Apologies if I have.

Comment: That is not a real Arduino Uno. It is some kind of clone product. Real Uno runs at 5V. The clone, it looks like it could be running at 3.3V because it has markings about 3.3V all over it. If your clone uses 3.3V supply, then all logic levels use 3.3V too, and CMOS chips running on 5V may not understand 3.3V logic levels properly, but the analyzer chip datasheet is so bad it does not state anything about this.

Comment: @Justme Yeah, it's a clone but the actual microcontroller is the same (ATmega328 ) so runs at the same voltage. The whole board is identical to an official board and the website says it runs between 5-9v. Thank you for your help. I think the chips must be broken because I've been looking at many different tutorials with the MSGEQ7 and they all have similar setups to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I bought about 10 circuitts MSGEQ7 from various dealers in Taiwan. But not a single one worked, even the oscillator did not swing. Only the purchase of original circuits from UK led to succes. The fault wasn't mine, and the circuit and software work exactly as described everywhere. Very simpli and fine, no critical timings, very easy. It is essential to feed the audio signal through a capacitor I found out. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work (Error establishing a database connection).
The MSGEQ7 **is not** a graphic equalizer where you can adjust the levels of seven frequency bands. Instead a translation error should have said that the IC is part of a display of the levels of seven frequency bands.